# How to I get the nearst items (neighbors) with knn?

Tags: python, algorithm, knn

I would like to provide suggestions as to which items are similar to each other. I'm using here for k-nearst-neighbors. Now my question is how do I get the nearest neighbors with the probability?
I would like to have something `[[item, probability] ..., [item n, probability n]]`.

How do I get such a list?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

list = [[0, 3, 8, 0], [0, 8, 7, 0], [0, 2, 9, 0], [1, 10, 10, 1], [2, 3, 8, 2], [2, 10, 10, 2], [3, 4, 12, 3], [3, 12, 4, 3], [3, 3, 8, 3], [4, 12, 4, 4], [4, 3, 8, 4], [4, 4, 12, 4], [5, 8, 7, 5], [5, 6, 13, 5], [5, 3, 8, 5], [6, 0, 3, 6], [6, 5, 11, 6], [6, 12, 4, 6], [7, 9, 6, 7], [7, 9, 6, 7], [8, 13, 5, 8], [9, 1, 0, 9], [9, 7, 2, 9], [9, 11, 1, 9], [9, 11, 1, 9]]
# Note: location isn't relevant
df = DataFrame (list,columns=['buyerid','itemid', 'group', 'location'])

sparse_item_user = sparse.csr_matrix((df['group'].astype(float), (df['itemid'], df['buyerid'])))
sparse_user_item = sparse.csr_matrix((df['group'].astype(float), (df['buyerid'], df['itemid'])))

model_knn= NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine', algorithm='brute', n_neighbors=20)
model_knn.fit(sparse_item_user)
desired_item = 8
model_knn.kneighbors(....) # Now get the nearst items
```

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by the probability? Nearest neighbor algorithms don't generally assign probabilities to anything.

Comment: @ADdV With the probability I simply mean the distance, I once read in a blog that the probability = proximity of the next element

Comment: I think you've misunderstood whatever blog that was. If you have two points, you can evaluate the "distance" between them. That doesn't have any intrinsic relationship to probability.

Answer (score 2):

From the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors), the following is the signature of kneighbors:

> `kneighbors(X=None, n_neighbors=None, return_distance=True)`

Thus, to get the nearest neighbor of some point `x`, you do `kneighbors(x, return_distance=True)`. In this case, n_neighbors was already specified in your constructor to be 20, so we need not give it here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what would `x` be in my case?

Comment: @Mr.Robot The nearest neighbor algorithm gives the nearest neighbors of "something". In this case, whatever you want to find the nearest neighbors of, that would be `x`.